# XML Serialization error in windows phone

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, serialization, windows-phone-8

I am trying to store values in Isolate Storage through XML serialization. I am getting the error as InvalidOperation Exception error. If i Debug line by line, value from the screen is passing and working fine through this process, variable "xml" is also showing the exact value which i need to get.  But in the below page you can see it is showing error at this point. Did I miss anything?

```
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

private UserModified _User = new UserModified();
private const string USER_KEY = "UserModified";

private void Jogger_JogLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains(USER_KEY))
        GetUser();

    this.DataContext = _User;
}
```

[image]

Comment: post the UserModified class too

Comment: Click on "View Detail..." and check if there is an InnerException.

Comment: @HenkHolterman InnerException -> InnerException :null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that it should be `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` not `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes`.